# how to parse from a string rather than a file

Tags: yacc, lex, flex-lexer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make  YY_INPUT point to a string rather than stdin in Lex & Yacc (Solaris)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920604/how-to-make-yy-input-point-to-a-string-rather-than-stdin-in-lex-yacc-solaris)

i want to parse from a string rather than a file. i know that v can use yy_scan_string fn to do it.but for me it's not working properly so pls help me

Comment: Post some code that illustrates your problem.

Comment: YY_BUFFER_STATE my_string_buffer = yy_scan_string(my_string);
    yyparse();
    yy_delete_buffer(my_string_buffer );

the parser errors out with a syntax error at the first token. I have verified that the grammar and the content of 'my_string' works using
 yyrestart(yyin) and also with yy_create_buffer() through a file.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1907847/15168.

Answer (score 5):

I fought through this problem myself very recently. The flex documentation on the subject leaves a bit to be desired.

I see two things right off the bat that might be tripping you up. First, note that your string needs to be **double NULL terminated**. That is, you need to take a regular, NULL terminated string and add ANOTHER NULL terminator at the end of it. That fact is buried in the flex documentation, and it took me a while to find as well.

Second, you've left off a call to "yy_switch_to_buffer". This is also not particularly clear from the documentation. If you change your code to something like this, it should work.

```
// add the second NULL terminator
int len = strlen(my_string);
char *temp = new char[ len + 2 ];
strcpy( temp, my_string );
temp[ len + 1 ] = 0; // The first NULL terminator is added by strcpy

YY_BUFFER_STATE my_string_buffer = yy_scan_string(temp); 
yy_switch_to_buffer( my_string_buffer ); // switch flex to the buffer we just created
yyparse(); 
yy_delete_buffer(my_string_buffer );
```

Comment: nope it's not working. it says YY_BUFFER_STATE is undeclared

Comment: (F)lex and Yacc/Bison are often used in C, less often in C++. Also, you should probably avoid calling `strlen()` twice on the same string.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the strlen issue... I suppose I should've taken the time to optimize my example code. ;)