# How to make  YY_INPUT point to a string rather than stdin in Lex & Yacc (Solaris)

Tags: c, solaris, yacc, lex

I want my `yylex()` to parse a string rather than a file or standard input.  How can I do it with the Lex and Yacc provided with Solaris?

Comment: See also [How to parse from a string rather than a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909166/how-to-parse-from-a-string-rather-than-a-file).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/1907847/15168.

Answer (score 15):

Redefine YY_INPUT.  Here's a working example, compile and run with the commands

```
yacc -d parser.y
lex lexer.l
gcc -o myparser *.c
```

Input is read from globalInputText.  You can modify this example so that global input text is whatever string you want or from any input source you want.

parser.y:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
extern void yyerror(char* s);
extern int yylex();
extern int readInputForLexer(char* buffer,int *numBytesRead,int maxBytesToRead);
%}

%token FUNCTION_PLUS FUNCTION_MINUS NUMBER

%%

expression:
    NUMBER FUNCTION_PLUS NUMBER { printf("got expression!  Yay!\n"); }
    ;

%%
```

lexer.l:

```
%{

#include "y.tab.h"
#include <stdio.h>


#undef YY_INPUT
#define YY_INPUT(b,r,s) readInputForLexer(b,&r,s)

%}

DIGIT   [0-9]
%%

\+      { printf("got plus\n"); return FUNCTION_PLUS; }
\-      { printf("got minus\n"); return FUNCTION_MINUS; }
{DIGIT}* { printf("got number\n"); return NUMBER; }
%%


void yyerror(char* s) {
    printf("error\n");
}

int yywrap() {
    return -1;
}
```

myparser.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int yyparse();
int readInputForLexer( char *buffer, int *numBytesRead, int maxBytesToRead );

static int globalReadOffset;
// Text to read:
static const char *globalInputText = "3+4";

int main() {
    globalReadOffset = 0;
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}

int readInputForLexer( char *buffer, int *numBytesRead, int maxBytesToRead ) {
    int numBytesToRead = maxBytesToRead;
    int bytesRemaining = strlen(globalInputText)-globalReadOffset;
    int i;
    if ( numBytesToRead > bytesRemaining ) { numBytesToRead = bytesRemaining; }
    for ( i = 0; i < numBytesToRead; i++ ) {
        buffer[i] = globalInputText[globalReadOffset+i];
    }
    *numBytesRead = numBytesToRead;
    globalReadOffset += numBytesToRead;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `numBytesRead` and `maxBytesToRead` should be `unsigned long *` and `unsigned long`, respectively.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the real `lex` and not `flex` I believe you can simply define your own

```
int input(void);
```

This can return characters from a string or whatever you want.

Alternatively, I believe you could write the string to a file, and open the file on stream `yyin`. I suspect this would work with either implementation.

If using flex then I think you redefine the `YY_INPUT()` macro,

Answer (score 3):

another approach is to use yy_scan_string as already mentioned in linked answers

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that should work with any implementation, although risky by using popen.

```
$ cat a.l
%%
"abc" {printf("got ABC\n");}
"def" {printf("got DEF\n");}
. {printf("got [%s]\n", yytext);}
%%
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return(lex("abcdefxyz"));
}
lex(char *s)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *cmd;
    cmd=malloc(strlen(s)+16);
    sprintf(cmd, "/bin/echo %s", s); // major vulnerability here ...
    fp=popen(cmd, "r");
    dup2(fileno(fp), 0);
    return(yylex());
}
yywrap()
{
    exit(0);
}
$ ./a
got ABC
got DEF
got [x]
got [y]
got [z]
```

Answer (score 0):

As was said before it can be done through redefining the `input()` - i've used it on aix, hpux and solaris.

Or another approach i use too is to make a pipe, and use `fdopen()`-ed `FILE*` as `yyin`.