# parsing compressed files with flex & bison?

Tags: c++, bison, lex

Is it possible to parse compressed files in flex?

`yyin` is a pointer of type `FILE*`. So I would like to do something like this: create a pipe of compressed file and set yyin to it?

Comment: No it's not possible, at least not directly. You need to uncompress it first.

Comment: Would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907847/how-to-use-yy-scan-string-in-lex

Comment: What would be your purpose in parsing a compressed file? It can be done, but as any compressed file is going to appear to be primarily random bytes (except for brief areas where metadata are stored), it's not going to follow any predictable rules that a parser would expect...

Comment: You will need to read the compressed data, uncompress it, then feed it in to flex. This can be done block by block. You will need something like zlib to read compressed blocks of data, uncompress it, then feed that block to `yylex()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `flex`, you can define the macro `YY_INPUT(buf,result,maxlen)` to change how `flex` obtains input. The macro must read *at most* `maxlen` bytes into `buf`, and return the actual number of bytes stored in `result`, or set `result` to `YY_NULL` to indicate EOF.

For example, using the convenience interface of `zlib`, you could insert something like the following into your flex file:

```
 %{

 #include <zlib.h>
 gzFile gz_yyin;
 #define YY_INPUT(buf,result,maxlen) do {  \
    int n = gzread(gz_yyin, buf, maxlen);  \
    if (n < 0) { /* handle the error */ }  \
    result = n > 0 ? n : YY_NULL;     \
 } while (0)

 %}

 // lots of stuff skipped

 int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   gz_yyin = gzopen(argv[1], "rb");
   if (gz_yyin == NULL) { /* handle the error */ }
   /* Start parsing */
   // ...
```

(You can use `gzdopen` to create a `gzfile` using an open file descriptor, such as a pipe.)